# How to convert QGIS 3.0 project to use auth_db ids

Tags: qgis-3, database, authentication

I am working on a Mac and running QGIS 3.0.3 and I am exploring the authentication db setup.

I have a bunch of layers almost all of which are based on PostGIS queries and I want to move all my authentication into the managed auth_db and it is not clear to me how to proceed.

I assume I will have to edit the project file and replace the database connection parameters with a reference to the id but how should I do this?

One thing I want to achieve with this exercise is to make the project files so they are independent of the user so I can share project files as a starting point for people .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by the simple expedient of adding a layer using the auth_db and then looking at what went into the project file.

user=<...>
gets replaced with authcfg=<...>

so in my case I edited the project file and performed the following replacement `Replace string user='rful011' -> authcfg=tiridb1`
Then I was able to open the project and have QGIS use the creds in the auth_db associated with 'tiridb1'.

I was surprised not to get prompted for the master passwords and did some more poking around and found that under Preference (Mac) -> Authentication-> Utilities there is a section about storing the master password in the OS keychain (Mac OS built in password manager) and it saves it by default.

[image]